# Google Map zoom / animation not responding

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map on one of my activities. The map is working well. However, I'd like to change the zoom and a few animations with the following code. However, none of this is responding. What am I missing? Thanks!

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(my_location.getLocationName()));

googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));

// Zoom in, animating the camera.
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());

// Zoom out to zoom level 10, animating with a duration of 2 seconds.
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
.target(latLng)         // Sets the center of the map to my coordinates
.zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
.bearing(180)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to south
.tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
.build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Comment: What does it mean "not responding" in terms of executed code?

Comment: I just mean that it's as if this code doesn't exist. There are no errors, warnings, or crashes. The zoom isn't setting to what I want and there is absolutely no animation whatsoever. If I commented out this code, my app would look exactly the same.

Comment: Does the code execute? Have you set a breakpoint?